# How to find the Number of factors, if sum of the factors are given?

Tags: prime-numbers, power-series, prime-factorization

A number is expressed in terms of $(2^m\times3^n)$, Find the value of $(m,n)$ if sum of all factors of a number is $124$.

Comment: The question really should have been about finding the solution(s) *efficiently*. It is clear that our number must be less than $124$, and there are not many numbers of the form $2^m3^n$ below $124$. And most of them obviously don't work, so a short search will do the job.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes, an exhaustive search would be perfectly good option... there would be $ 2^{\{0..6\}}, 3\cdot2^{\{0..5\}}, 3^2\cdot2^{\{0..3\}}, 3^3\cdot2^{\{0..2\}}$ and $3^4$, a total of $21$ possibilities, which you could also certainly check in an optimal way.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the factors of $2^m3^n$ is $$\frac{2^{m+1}-1}{2-1}\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1} = \frac{(2^{m+1}-1)(3^{n+1}-1)}{2} = 124\qquad\text{(given)}$$
Therefore $(2^{m+1}-1)(3^{n+1}-1)=248$. Factors of $248$ are $2^3\cdot 31$; clearly $m+1=5$ and $n+1=2$ then $(m,n)=(4,1)$

Comment: If $m=5$ and $n=2$, the number would be $2^5\cdot 3^2=288$.  The sum of factors of $288$ is certainly not $124$.

Comment: @paw88789 Damn, you are of course correct, modifying to add the relvant constant... sigh.